# Script for splitting one cell into two with only space as delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a long list of names and email addressees in a single column of an excel sheet.
The format is as following:

```
Smith,John <john.smith@ourcompany.com>
```

I need to separate the name from the email address and split them in two columns.
The only delimiter between the name and the email address is a space.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no other spaces in the names, in Excel 2007+, you can simply use: Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > Space > Finish.

If there are spaces in the names that approach won't work well.

Comment: Whooa, what kind of strange sorcery is this!? Thank you assylias you are my hero.